# Why does explain plan show the wrong number of rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to simulate [this](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-index/oracle-bitmap-index/#:%7E:text=A%20bitmap%20index%20is%20a,column%20of%20the%20members%20table.) and to do that I have created the following procedure to insert a large number of rows:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE a_lot_of_rows is
    i carte.cod%TYPE;
    a carte.autor%TYPE := 'Author #';
    t carte.titlu%TYPE := 'Book #';
    p carte.pret%TYPE := 3.23;
    e carte.nume_editura%TYPE := 'Penguin Random House';

begin
    for i in 8..1000 loop
        insert into carte
        values (i, e, a || i, t || i, p, 'hardcover');
        commit;
    end loop;

    for i in 1001..1200 loop
        insert into carte
        values (i, e, a || i, t || i, p, 'paperback');
        commit;
    end loop;

end;
```

I have created a bitmap index on the tip_coperta column (which can only have the values 'hardcover' and 'paperback') and then inserted 1200 more rows. However, the result given by the explain plan is the following (before the insert procedure, the table had 7 rows, of which 4 had the tip_coperta = 'paperback'):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |     4 |   284 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARTE |     4 |   284 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("TIP_COPERTA"='paperback')
```

Comment: Note also that your query **does not** use any index  - `TABLE ACCESS FULL`

Answer (score 3):

**Motto: Bad Statistics are Worse than No Statistics**

**TLDR** your statistics are stale and need to be recollected. If you create index the  *index* statistics are automatically gathered but *not the table statistics* that are relevant for your case.

Lets simulate your example with the following script to create the table and fill it with 1000 hardcovers and 200 paperbacks.

```
create table CARTE 
(cod int,
 autor VARCHAR2(100),
 titlu VARCHAR2(100),
 pret NUMBER,
 nume_editura  VARCHAR2(100),
 tip_coperta VARCHAR2(100)
); 


insert into CARTE
(cod,autor,titlu,pret,nume_editura,tip_coperta)
select rownum,
       'Author #'||rownum ,
       'Book #'||rownum,
       3.23,
       'Penguin Random Number',
       case when rownum <=1000 then 'hardcover'
       else 'paperback' end
from dual connect by level <= 1200;       
commit;
```

This leaves the new table without *optimizer object statistics*, which you can verfiy with the following query that return only `NULL`s

```
select NUM_ROWS, LAST_ANALYZED from user_tables where table_name = 'CARTE';
```

So, let's check what is the Oracle impression of the table:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from CARTE 
where tip_coperta = 'paperback'
;
--    
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));
```

The script above produce the execution plan for your query asking for `paberback`s and you see that the `Rows` is fine (= 200). How is this possible?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |   200 | 46800 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARTE |   200 | 46800 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("TIP_COPERTA"='paperback')
```

The explanation is in the Notes of the plan output - the dynamic sampling was used.

Basically Oracle execute while parsing the query an additional query to estimate the number of rows with the filter predicate.

```
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Dynamic sampling is fine for tables that are used seldon, but if the table is queried regularly, we need optimizer statsitics *to save the overhead of dynamic sampling*.

So **let's collect statistics**

```
 exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>user, tabname=>'CARTE' );
```

Now you see that the statistics are gathered, the total number of rows is fine and
in the *column statistics* a `frequency` histogram is created - this is important to estimate the count of records with a specific value!

```
select NUM_ROWS, LAST_ANALYZED from user_tables where table_name = 'CARTE';

  NUM_ROWS LAST_ANALYZED      
---------- -------------------
      1200 09.01.2021 16:48:26
      
select NUM_DISTINCT,HISTOGRAM  from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'CARTE' and column_name = 'TIP_COPERTA'; 

NUM_DISTINCT HISTOGRAM      
------------ ---------------
           2 FREQUENCY
```

Lets vefiry how the statistics are working now in the execution plan

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from CARTE 
where tip_coperta = 'paperback'
;
--    
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));
```

Basically we see the **same correct result**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |   200 | 12400 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARTE |   200 | 12400 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("TIP_COPERTA"='paperback')
```

Now we delete all but the four 'paperback's from the table

```
delete from   CARTE 
where tip_coperta = 'paperback' and cod > 1004;
commit;

select count(*) from CARTE 
where tip_coperta = 'paperback'

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4
```

With this action the  **statistics went stale** and give a wrong  result based on obsolet data. This wrong result will occure until the statistics are recollected.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from CARTE 
where tip_coperta = 'paperback'
;
--    
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |   200 | 12400 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARTE |   200 | 12400 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Set up a policy that maintains your statistics up-to-date!**

Comment: Thank you @JonHeller - like my English;)

Answer (score 2):

It is the table statistics that are important for this cardinality.

You will need to wait until the automatic stats gathering task to fire up and obtain the new statistics, or you can do it yourself:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'carte',method_opt=>'for all columns size 1 for columns size 254 TIP_COPERTA')
```

This will force there to be a histogram on the `TIP_COPERTA` column and not on the others (you may wish to use `for all columns size skew` or `for all columns size auto` or even just let it default to whatever the set preferred `method_opt` parameter is. Have a read of [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-does-the-methodopt-parameter-work) for details about this parameter.

In some of the later versions of Oracle, depending on where you are running it, you may also have [Real-Time Statistics](https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/real-time-statistics-19c). This is where Oracle will be keeping your statistics up to date even after conventional DML.

It's important to remember that cardinality estimates do not need to be completely accurate for you to obtain reasonable execution plans. A common rule of thumb is that it should be within an order of magnitude, and even then you will probably be fine most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain an estimate for the number of rows, Oracle needs you to analyze the table (or index).  When you create an index, there is an automatic analyze.

Comment: I've dropped the bitmap index and then created it again, but I am still getting the same number of rows for the explained plan.

Comment: Perhaps your actions did not invalidate the plan that Oracle keeps in memory.  It's been a while, I seem to remember you had to indicate if an index drop should invalidate existing plans.  Also, very interesting to philosophize about an explain plan without knowing what statement it is about.